# Which reference frame in our solar system experiences the most time?

Tags: time, solar-system, relativity

Suppose we must choose a location in our solar system for a self-sustaining space-station. Imagine that the station will house experiments which must be completed as quickly as possible for the benefit of all humankind, and these efforts will be ongoing, so long-term productivity is the dominant concern.

For this reason, we want time in this station to progress as quickly as possible relative to the rest of the solar system. The station is allowed to be attached to a stable body, or it can reside in any stable orbit.

It seems we need general relativity to solve this problem, and I do not know where to begin.

Comment: As far from the sun as possible, with rockets keeping it from falling into the sun (do not orbit.) This minimizes both gravity and velocity. Note that this will in fact be negligible compared to the earth.

Comment: What I would recommend though, is to *slow down* humanity a lot, relative the experiments. This provides great gains.

Comment: I am also interested in ways to accomplish that, since both *should* be done if possible. It's a separate question though, and there's the extra restriction that the majority of the population isn't allowed to know that anything like this is going on.

Comment: Sorry to say, but making things experience more time is generally not very possible (unless you magically acquire negative mass stuff.) On the other hand, slowing things down is *very* possible, which is what you will want to focus on.

Comment: You may want to see [this question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/how-would-humans-adapt-their-language-in-response-to-moving-through-time-at-diff). Specifically read the premise. Simple place computers in a non-time dilated frame, and it will go faster relative to the humans.

Comment: Depends on how fast relative to anything in the solar system.

Comment: Can you give an example of an experiment that must be completed and yet is on-going? It seems like a contradiction and will affect the answer.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Individual experiments must be completed as quickly as possible, and there will be a never-ending series of experiments, so overall efforts will be ongoing. You can safely assume that it's fruitful medical research and that progress is certain to prolong human lives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Oort Cloud.**

As PyRulez said, as far from mass and as slow as possible. Hanging out in the [Oort Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oort_cloud) will get you as close to [Barycentric Coordinate Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_Coordinate_Time) as possible. This is the "fastest" (least slowed) time you could hope get while staying in the solar system.

However, I hope your experiments are *incredibly* efficient and *incredibly* long duration because the best you're going to get is about 490 milliseconds per year faster than on Earth. It's hard to say if that is worth the cost of setting up a lab in the Oort Cloud. Generally I would think not, but perhaps you have a compelling reason.

Comment: A back of the envelope calculation says you'd have to run it for perhaps half a million years before that half-second per year offset the time lag from signalling the calculation back home...

Comment: But the oort cloud contains mass. See my Answer for

Comment: @JDługosz Your answer *adds* mass. It is not correct.

Comment: The only way to improve this would be if you had an unlimited supply of antimatter and solar system wide legal immunity.